# Set TD Width To Width Of Largest Span

Tags: html, css

I am currently having an issue with TD widths; no matter the length of the spans within the TD elements, it stays a consistent width. I need the TD elements to be completely resized to the width of the longest span element contained within the same column.

```css
.Form {
  width: 100%;
}
.Form td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.Form td > span {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.Form td > input[type="text"] {
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: -2px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  width: 99%;
}
```

```html
<table class="Form">
        <tr><td colspan="6"><h3>Some super header text with useful information.</h3></td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan="6"><h3>Other useful information.</h3></td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span>LONGEST EVER</span></td>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="text" id="txtPOC" runat="server" /></td>
            <td><span>Phone</span></td>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="text" id="txtPhone" runat="server" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span>Short</span></td>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="text" id="txtOrg" runat="server" /></td>
            <td><span>E-Mail</span></td>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="text" id="txtMail" runat="server" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

[image]

Comment: what is the problem? you want input to be 100% width as `LONGEST EVER` span? or every td to be 100% width of the screen?

Comment: Editing post to clarify